# My divs are stacking, but I want them to just float next to each other

Tags: css, css-float

I'm floating four divs to the left, trying to get them to sit next to each other. However, they're all stacking one on top of the other. Any thoughts?

My problem is in the footer of aogaragedoor.com. Click on Areas Served and you'll see the word 'Filler' appear in the left. It's a WordPress site, and it's actually four widgets each holding a custom menu, and they all have just one placeholder link for now, Filler.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: hard to say what you are doing wrong without seeing your code.  do you want to post some code (or a jsfiddle) to help us help you?

Comment: try this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842168/align-divs-horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the negative bottom margin in `style.css`:

```
ul.xoxo {
    margin:0 0 -20px 25px;  # <-- Set bottom margin to 0
}
```