# 3 divs won't align in a horizontal row

Tags: html, css

I've tried everything and looked at many relevant discussions on here but nothing has helped. I'm designing it through Dreamweaver and when I look at the design in D.W all 3 divs are in a row but in the ie browser the divs are in a column.

HTML

```
      div class="container">
<div id="news" class="fluid">
  <div align="center">News</div>
    <div align="center">VOLUNTEERS THE HEART OF THE COMMUNITY<br>
    Volunteers wanted in our three charity shops in Worthing. Read more..</div>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="events" class="fluid">
<div align="center">"events"</div>   </div>
     <div id="newsletter" class="fluid">
       <div align="center"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
text-align: center;
clear: none;
   }

    #news {
width: 32.2033%;
clear:none;
    background-color: rgba(232,138,12,0.57);
    }
      #events {
clear:none;
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
      width: 33.7288%;
background-color: rgba(20,18,241,1.57);
    }

   #newsletter {
background-color: rgba(16,203,225,1.57);
      width: 20.2033%;
   clear:none;

     }
```

The url is http://www.worthingscope.org.uk/newindex.html 
Any help would be great
Many thanks.

Comment: `float: left` is your friend. PS: While I'm here, the artefacts on that Scope logo are horrendous.

Comment: I see a lot more than three divs here. And why does your CSS contain `clear:none` everywhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align divs horizontally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842168/align-divs-horizontally)

Comment: Strongly agree with Philip. Why don't you use Bootstrap or something like that. Make your life so much more easy and beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove `clear: none;` wherever you have it; it's not doing anything useful. Second, as user j08691 mentioned, there are more than three divs here, so it's not 100% clear which ones you want aligned horizontally. I will assume it's the ones with `.fluid` as a class, however. So you can do something like this:

```
.fluid {
    float: left;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1t3cv7x6/)**